# Check if nested associations has object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have here a line of code that checks if `name` column exists in `user.identity` object. It do not fail if `user` object has `identity`. But it fails when `user` object doesn't have an `identity` value.

```
text += "Print me: \n" if @user.identity.name.present? && !@user.identity.phone.active?
```

I would like to check first if `identity` exist. How can I do it in a neat way? Is there any method to check chains of nested objects?

I'm trying to avoid long conditions of `ifs` as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use `try` (if you use it once, you have to use it all the way after that)

```
if @user.try(:identity).try(:name).present?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` while calling `name` like this:

```
text += "Print me: \n" if @user.identity.try(:name).present? && !@user.identity.try(:phone).active?
```

**Note:** Because `try` check lot many other things, `try` is not preferred in terms of performance, just to avoid checking whether last method can call next or not. You may want to try this (more readable & preferred):

```
id = @user.identity
text += "Print me: \n" if id && id.name.present? && !id.phone.active?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in following way:

```
text += "Print me: \n" if @user.try(:identity).try(:name) && !@user.try(:identity).try(:phone).try(:active?)
```